# Touchpad super slow on Acer E5-574G with Loki

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, laptop, input, acer

I have an Acer E5-574G laptop, which came with Windows 10. Recently I installed Elementary OS (Loki). Everything worked but my touchpad became super slow. When I rub my finger over touchpad, it moves the cursor very slow. I have also tried to increase the speed from settings but the issue remains. I have already contact with Acer—they said they don't provide any driver for Linux. What I can do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP didn't post their solution, but I'd wager that the answer was to [change the trackpad settings in the Acer BIOS](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/36865/~/changing-the-precision-touchpad-settings-in-the-bios), where "Touchpad" should be set to "Basic".

You can also follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI2H8g6rM6E).

[image: BIOS]

Answer (score 0):

The elementary team issued a [fix for trackpad issues](http://blog.elementary.io/post/150787296131/loki-release-follow-up) recently.

Is your system up-to-date with the most recent version? You can check in AppCenter under the section Updates or alternatively upgrade your system by typing the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved, I posted this issue on several forums so, I got solution from one of them, I only edit touch pad setting in my bios, It was set to Advance I have set it to Basic and its working perfect for me.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to post more of the solution (and link to the forum) so that others can benefit from the knowledge?